# How to disable a button when the 1st row in a custom picker view is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a custom UIPickerView class (also conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource) that is used in 2 view controllers. 
So in both of them I have this: 
`myPickerView.delegate = myPickerView` and same with `dataSource`.
All the rows and components are configured in that custom picker view class.

I want to disable a button in my VCs when the 1st row is selected. 
Usually I would do this by using one of the picker view's delegate functions (`pickerView(_:,didSelectRow:, inComponent:`), but since I use a custom one that already conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate, I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, tricky. The issue is that the picker is its own delegate, which makes the solution a bit complicated, but here's what I might do: give the picker a closure that gets called when the selected row changes. Then call that closure from the delegate method.

```
class MyPickerView {
    typealias SelectedIndexClosure = (Int) -> Void
    var selectedIndexClosure: SelectedIndexClosure = { _ in }

...

    func picker(_ picker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int ...) {
        selectedIndexClosure(row)
    }
}
```

Then you'd set the `selectedIndexClosure` to whatever code you want to be run in the view controller.

```
myPickerView.selectedIndexClosure = { [weak self] index in
    self?.button.enabled = (index == 1)
}
```

And that should do. An more idiomatic solution might be to refactor the picker's datasource and delegate methods into a new, separate object owned by the view controller, but this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can say `self.button.isEnabled = self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0` if you just need to set it once.  If you need it to be reenabled after moving the picker, or disabled if you move back to the first row, you will need to use that same delegate method.

Comment: Yeah, I need it to trigger every time the user selected the 1st row. It doesn't seem like I can add an @IBAction to a picker view, it only shows that I can add an `Outlet` or an `Outlet collection`.
How can I use the same delegate method though? I can't override it or extend the class

Comment: @PavelOrel Huh - I guess you're right.  You can for date pickers, but not regular ones.  Go figure.